# Uncaught ReferenceError: date0 is not defined after removeAttribute

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I have a readonly field:

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="date0" value="" valid="required;date" readonly="" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
```

So I'm trying to set value="01.01.2021" with removeAttribyute and setAttribute:

```
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("date0")[0].removeAttribute("readonly")');
driver.execute_script('document.getElementsByName("date0")[0].setAttribute("value", "01.01.2021")')
```

Then my field is:

```
<input type="text" size="10" maxlength="10" name="date0" value="01.01.2021" valid="required;date" style="background-color:lightgrey;">
```

... but I have an error message (Firefox) "Uncaught ReferenceError: date0 is not defined". What's wrong?

Comment: Show your full code.

Comment: Possibly the error is coming from the next line of your code which you need to show us.